# Sending POST data in Android and change the Sites

Tags: android, post, cookies, android-asynctask, session-cookies

I want to login to a website via post in my webview. This is working fine but if I click on the buttons on this site I am redirected back to the login page. How can I save the login so I need to login again? Should i use cookies to solve the problem? I already tried with cookies but that didnt solved the problem.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(MainActivity.this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

}

private class LoadWebPageASYNC extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";


            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example/index.php?s=login");

            try {
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "id"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "pass"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "login"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }



        return result;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CookieManager.setCookie(); 
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://example/index.php?s=login", result, "text/html", "BASE64", null);

    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void dummyFunc(View view){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void readWebpage(View view) {
    LoadWebPageASYNC task = new LoadWebPageASYNC();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://example/index.php?s=login" });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use the cookie.

Comment: okey but I already tried to solve the problem with cookies but it doesnt worked too...